# Upgrading RAM on a 32-bit system to boost up android studio?

Tags: android, windows, performance, android-studio, ram

I have a system with configuration

[image]

I am planning to upgrade my 2GB DDR2 RAM to 4GB. Actually my Android Studio lags on my system (even though I used to test apps using my phone) and sometimes the editor lags when I have two or more system applications open.

Should I upgrade my RAM ? (I cant afford to buy a new system now )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, upgrading your RAM will provide the biggest performance boost for the least cost. The bottleneck in build times and lag will be from low RAM and using HDD instead of SDD

Comment: Don't you think the processor needs to be upgraded too?

Comment: Ideally, yeah, but RAM would be the most cost-effective

Comment: Agreed. By the way, is this even the right place for such a question? I thought this was a place only for software and programming related issues

Comment: Nope, not really the place haha